# Explain tolerances in technical drawing

Tags: mechanical, technical-drawing, tolerance

I'm not a mechanical engineer and am not used to looking at mechanical drawings. I'm trying to understand what these tolerance features mean.

[image]

[image]
There is a positional tolerance feature, which references datum A. But, what exactly is it specifying? That the middle point of the flat must be within 0.1 mm of the rotational axis? Or the thickness of the disc?

[image]

Comment: surface flatness or runout?

Comment: @SolarMike As far as I'm aware, total runout is noted by two parallel arrows, joined at the bottom by a line. This is a positional tolerance, i.e. a circle with a cross in it.

Comment: The image provided does not give me that detail - all I get is some amorphous blob

Comment: @SolarMike Apologies for that, Mike. The copy I have is a little dodgy, but on my version, I can see it's a positional tolerance. What I'm trying to understand is what datum A specifically refers to? It seems to me like datum A is the direction perpendicular to the perimeter of the circle.

Comment: There are **tons** of websites which list mech drawing symbology and their meanings.

Comment: @lmsavk can you post more of the drawing? What is Datum A? I see an A on the drawing, but I don't see a correct datum symbol. It looks like part of that feature control frame is missing. Is there a secondary datum reference?

Comment: @GisMofx Apologies. It's updated now.

Comment: @lmsavk Is this a professionally drawn part? Does the title block say which GDT spec it is drawn to? I.e ASME Y14.5-2009. I've only seen holes or centerlines of circular/radial features use position. I think the feature would make more sense as a profile instead of tolerance of position and would interpret it as such with approval from the designer of that part.

Comment: @GisMofx it just says that "General Tolerance to ISO 2768-M". I've ended up assuming that this is saying that the flat has a tolerance zone in its width of +- 0.1.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a related mating envelope related to datum A for the three plates, per ASME Y14.5-2009.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It says the flats shall be within 0.100 units of radial dimension positioned with reference to 'A'.

i.e. if you were to make the rim which is a perfect circle, then mill the flats at the three positions, what you should see is that the flats are exactly the same sectional shape and size if the machinist was perfectly precise.

Some minor deviation from that precision (+/- 0.1 units) is permitted which limits the variability of size and position of the cut.

Why? Perhaps a precision tool is needed or the mating piece has a similar tolerance, to ensure a good fit.